# Date popup form field doesn't show the default value correctly

Tags: 7, forms

I am creating a custom form with "date_popup" form fields.
The only issue I have is that the default_value for the date popup form field shows only the first digit of the year, not the whole date.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I can't find the issue for it right now but it used to be that you had to set the `#default_value` in a very specific format to get it to work...`'#default_value' => date('Y-m-d', $date)`

Comment: Thanks,Clive. Yes, it is set the right way. After debugging i've found it turns wrong after pre_render function called ctools_smth_pre_render.Currently don't remember it's name clearly. Possibly it conflicts with ctools module.Going to investigate further later. Currently it looks this way:$form['all']['start'] = array(
   '#type' => 'date_popup',
   '#size' => 30,
   '#title' => t('Begin at Date'),
   '#maxlength' => 30,
   '#date_format' => 'Y-M-d','#default_value' => date('Y-M-d', $date),

  );

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clive was absolutely right: The default value MUST be set using the date format "Y-m-d", such as with `date('Y-m-d', $date)`.

The difference is that I used "Y-M-d" instead of "Y-m-d" for #default_value.

Comment: What a pain! The original issue was [here](http://drupal.org/node/509036) in case you're interested

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8:

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

$form['mydatefield']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($mydatestring));
```

Comment: great addition, works good in D8