# Default date in date popup in drupal 6

Tags: datetime

I am using the following code to display a date popup in my drupal 6 custom module.

```
 $form['intelligence']['start_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_year_range' => '-100:+0',
    '#description'=>'Start',
    '#prefix' => '<div class="start_datefield_div"> ', 
    '#date_format' => 'Y-M-d',
    '#default_value' => date('Y-M-d',  time()),
    '#suffix'=>'</div>'
 );
```

But I am getting default date blank.

I have gone through [Date popup form field doesn't show the default value correctly](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41012/date-popup-form-field-doesnt-show-the-default-value-correctly) and 
[string espected but array given in custom pop_date field #default_value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51519/string-espected-but-array-given-in-custom-pop-date-field-default-value) , but no success .

Can anybody tell, what the issue is with this code? Actually I need `$_POST['start_date']` as the default value. But for testing purpose I put `date('Y-M-d',  time())`

Comment: Look at the examples on the other questions a bit more closely: `'#default_value' => date('Y-m-d', $date)`. Notice the lower case 'm'; it's counter-intuitive but date_popup is expecting the default value in a very specific format, regardless of the format you've chosen for display

Comment: I changed the code to  
 $form['intelligence']['start_date'] = array(
     '#type' => 'date_popup',
     '#date_year_range' => '-100:+0',
     '#description'=>'Start',
     '#prefix' => '<div class="start_datefield_div"> ', 
     '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
     '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d',  time()),
     '#suffix'=>'</div>'
     );,but still it is blank

Comment: Default value should be in the format "Y-m-d H:i:s", regardless of what you use as your display format.