# Set default value for time field in custom form

Tags: 7, datetime

I am trying to set a default value for time field only in a custom form using date module API. The code is as follows:

```
    $today = strtotime('00:00:00');
    $form['schedule_this_node']['scheduled_time'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y h:i A',
    '#date_year_range' => '0:+3',
    '#title' => t('Schedule At'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => date('H:i', $today),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('date-picker')),
```

But the above code does not set a default value.Does #default_value works only in date('Y-m-d H:i', $today) format only with date API? is it related to [Date popup form field doesn't show the default value correctly](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41012/date-popup-form-field-doesnt-show-the-default-value-correctly)?

Comment: thanks @Mołot, the answer says we have to set it in format date('Y-m-d'), so just want to confirm if there is no way around to only set the time field leaving the date field blank

Comment: It certainly seems so.